# TYPO3 Extbase Framework - Repository Directory Function & Documentation

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I'm new to TYPO3 `Extbase` framework. I'm unsure about what the purpose of the `repository` directory is. What is its purpose? Also, where can I find some documentation for this framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Repositories` contains methods for fetching the `Model's` objects.

See this blog: [How to Effectively use the Repository and Query Object of Extbase?](http://blog.typoplanet.de/2010/01/27/the-repository-and-query-object-of-extbase/)

There is also [Wiki for Extbase](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki) available

The fastest way to learn Extbase is using [Extension Builder](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder) you'll build your first (and next too :)) `Extbase` extension, if you'll choose some default actions while modeling it will create all required stuff, also repositories. At the beginning they are empty however they inherits methods like findAll(), findByUid() etc.

Tip: use good IDE (ie. PhpStorm) which can understand Extbase, it will help you learn faster and better.

Comment: When i tried Extension Builder , i got an error like this . Fatal error: Call to a member function findAll()

Comment: Sorry i have fixed this issue .. Since i am new guy in this i forgot to update you about this . The problem was i forgot to include the model class .